# Why does a float css property resize a div's size?

Tags: css, html, css-float

Given the following style:

```
#myDiv{
  background:orange;
  width:250px;
}
```

and the following HTML code:

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <p>
        Vote Pirates!<br />
    </p>
</div>
```

*Why exactly* would it change the size of the div when I add a `float:left` property to the myDiv style?

Edit: Turns out this is a browser-issue, or even worse an operating system specific problem.

Comment: Not for me. http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/QXJEZ

Comment: The size of the div won't change. What behavior are you experiencing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like the likely answer: *A floated box is taken out of the flow, so it doesn’t affect the block-level boxes around it.*

Lifted from [this page](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/floatclear) on sitepoint.

Also, you might be experiencing browser specific functionality (errors?).  Are you using IE 6.0?

Comment: The size of the example does change here. This is Firefox 5 / 64bit on Fedora Core 15. But you may be right, in Opera it does not change.

Answer (score 1):

The size of your current example won't change.

Elements with relative units, however, will change. The `float` property rips an element from their current context, resulting in a possibly different height/width.

Comment: I've also found a nice tutrial for you: http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/