# When applied a CSS float property redraws its parent's dimensions

Tags: html, css, styles, css-float

Given the following HTML code:

```
<html>
<body>
<head>
<style>

#myDiv{
  background:orange;
  width:300px;

}

.a{
  margin:5px;
  background:purple;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myDiv">
  <p class="a">A<br>A</p>
  <p class="b">B</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Why is it that when I add `float:right` to `.a`, the myDiv shrinks?

Would you agree with my answer?

> Because CSS floats are positioning properties. The paragraph
>   referenced to as 'a' is positioned with a float CSS property and
>   breaks out of the flow of the div 'myDiv'. That's why the 'a' element
>   is  positioned at the right corner of the div 'myDiv'. The browser
>   renders 'myDiv' without the floating paragraph 'a'. That is why the
>   browser only draws a background behind the node value of the paragraph
>   referenced to as 'b' and stretches it 300 pixels wide, following the
>   CSS declaration of the html head element.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does a float css property resize a div's size?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800280/why-does-a-float-css-property-resize-a-divs-size)

Comment: [Block formatting contexts](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting)

Comment: @Kyle Sevenoaks: This one has more context. He probably didn't want to edit his existing one lest it made the existing answers/comments obsolete.

Comment: Yea I wanted to break it down in more questions. Well we could delete the other one and if you'd like this one too, b/c I think my answer is quite good.

Comment: True, but the OP can always append edits to the bottom of the question.

Answer (score -1):

you may like this

```
<div id="myDiv">
  <p class="a">A<br>A</p>
  <p class="b">B</p>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: "Why is it that when I add `float:right` to `.a`, the myDiv shrinks?" "you may like this workaround" ???